# Android: using mask to cut away parts of an image

Tags: android, image, transparent, mask

I have a blue image. Also, I also have a mask image that has the same size.
In the mask image there are white borders. 
I'd like to set areas from the blue image transparent where the mask is white.
What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Check this link out, about **PorterDuffXferModes**: http://www.piwai.info/transparent-jpegs-done-right/